# What are some simple examples of algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra, algebras

So an algebra $A$ over a field $K$  is a ring under the operations $+$ and $x$ and also a vector space under a scalar operation and the operation $+$.

What are some examples of algebras? When rings are introduced there’s plenty of trivial examples, but I can’t seem to find any simple examples on algebras?

Thank you.

Comment: Polynomial rings are an example. Real valued functions on a topological space are an example. If you are familiar with modules, algebras are like rings that are are also modules.

Comment: Do you really think it's useful to ask people "What are some simple examples that aren't trivial?" Nobody knows what you think "trivial" or "simple" mean, or indeed even if there is any tangible difference...  You should, at a minimum, listed types you already know and don't want to have listed again.

Comment: Polynomials in noncommuting variables is a good example.

Answer (score 4):

Fields are algebras over themselves, and any ring containing a field in its center is an algebra over that field.

Then there's polynomial rings over fields, power series rings over fields, rings of functions on fields, matrix rings over fields, group rings over fields, direct products of any of the above (all being algebras over the common field.)

So even with just $\mathbb Q,\mathbb R,\mathbb C$, you should already be able to construct at least a dozen interestingly different algebras using it.

Actually, it is a thing that algebras are also defined over *commutative rings*. Doing it that way, every ring with characteristic $0$ and with identity is a $\mathbb Z$ algebra, and the ones with positive characteristic are algebras over $\mathbb Z_n$ for different $n$'s.